# Changing the font in every second line of the table

Tags: tables, fonts, formatting, automation, rowcolor

I've already found solutions here that work over `\rowfont{}` but not automatically adjust by even and odd number of lines.

I think about a case function it would work well for the first lines and then for the next. Unfortunately I don't understand the syntax and possibilities in LaTeX. Could someone please give me a solution for the problem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\endtabular}{\rowfont{}}% Clear row font
\makeatother
\newcommand{\rowfonttype}{}% Current row font
\newcommand{\rowfont}{% Set current row font
    \gdef\rowfonttype{\color{white}}%
}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\rowfonttype}l}

\rowcolors{1}{blue}{orange}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{LL}               
        \rowfont
        \textbf{Hello}& \textbf{World} \\
        \textcolor{Black}{Foo} & \textcolor{Black}{Bar} \\ 
        Hello & World
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve your needs easily with a TikZ matrix.

The options `every odd row` and `every even row` allow you to set a style for even and odd rows without complicated code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \matrix [
        matrix of nodes, 
        nodes in empty cells,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,% if you don't want a visible separation between columns
        column 1/.style={
            nodes={text width=3em},%put the width you prefer here
            },
        column 2/.style={
            nodes={text width=4em},%put the width you prefer here
            },
        every odd row/.style={
            nodes={fill=blue, text=white},
            },
        every even row/.style={
            nodes={fill=orange},
            },
        every node/.style={
            font=\bfseries,  
            text height=1.75ex,
            text depth=.25ex,
            align=left
            },
        ] {
        Hello & World \\
        Foo & Bar \\ 
        Hello & World\\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ti*k*Z allows us to do a lot of crazy things - thank you for share `every odd/even row`!!